# node:18-alpine image not working with podman 4.5.0 on ventura 13.3

Tags: node.js, qemu, alpine-linux, podman

Since I upgraded my machine to Ventura(13.3.1), my podman 4.5.0 is giving issues with running node alpine images. I am getting openssl errors. The arm based image works fine.

```
podman run --rm -it --name=test_ssl_error --platform linux/amd64 node:18-alpine apk upgrade

fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
48CB8A0240000000:error:0200008A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:invalid padding:crypto/rsa/rsa_pk1.c:75:
48CB8A0240000000:error:02000072:rsa routines:rsa_ossl_public_decrypt:padding check failed:crypto/rsa/rsa_ossl.c:606:
48CB8A0240000000:error:1C880004:Provider routines:rsa_verify:RSA lib:providers/implementations/signature/rsa_sig.c:774:
48CB8A0240000000:error:06880006:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_verify_ctx:EVP lib:crypto/asn1/a_verify.c:217:
48CB8A0240000000:error:0A000086:SSL routines:tls_post_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1889:
ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/main: Permission denied
WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/main: No such file or directory
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
48CB8A0240000000:error:0200008A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:invalid padding:crypto/rsa/rsa_pk1.c:75:
48CB8A0240000000:error:02000072:rsa routines:rsa_ossl_public_decrypt:padding check failed:crypto/rsa/rsa_ossl.c:606:
48CB8A0240000000:error:1C880004:Provider routines:rsa_verify:RSA lib:providers/implementations/signature/rsa_sig.c:774:
48CB8A0240000000:error:06880006:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_verify_ctx:EVP lib:crypto/asn1/a_verify.c:217:
48CB8A0240000000:error:0A000086:SSL routines:tls_post_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1889:
ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/community: Permission denied
WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/community: No such file or directory
OK: 9 MiB in 17 packages
```

My podman machine info is as follows. What steps can I take to troubleshoot this problem?

```
podman machine info
Host:
  Arch: arm64
  CurrentMachine: podman-machine-default
  DefaultMachine: ""
  EventsDir: /var/folders/3c/981sn8bj57s0hzf135y350w00000gp/T/podman-run--1/podman
  MachineConfigDir: /Users/agautam/.config/containers/podman/machine/qemu
  MachineImageDir: /Users/agautam/.local/share/containers/podman/machine/qemu
  MachineState: Running
  NumberOfMachines: 1
  OS: darwin
  VMType: qemu
Version:
  APIVersion: 4.5.0
  Built: 1681478900
  BuiltTime: Fri Apr 14 15:28:20 2023
  GitCommit: 75e3c12579d391b81d871fd1cded6cf0d043550a
  GoVersion: go1.20.3
  Os: darwin
  OsArch: darwin/arm64
  Version: 4.5.0
```

Adding more context.
I am running apple silicon and using qemu v 8.0 for running amd images on podman default machine.

```
rpm-ostree install -r qemu-user-static
```

I cannot use an ARM image, I need to use amd based image

Comment: It's worth checking that the image is published for arm64 architecture. If it isn't then I think the docker protcol will serve up whatever architecture it can find (which usually then just fails of course)

Comment: This seems relevant, although I'm not qualified to understand exactly what it is on about:
https://github.com/docker-library/official-images#architectures-other-than-amd64

Comment: Adding platform switch removes the platform mismatch warning(updated the issue description) but the openssl issue is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening due to a regression in qemu. Please use following option to create a new podman machine until it is fixed

```
podman machine init --cpus 2 --memory 4096 --volume /Users:/Users --image-path https://builds.coreos.fedoraproject.org/prod/streams/stable/builds/37.20230122.3.0/aarch64/fedora-coreos-37.20230122.3.0-qemu.aarch64.qcow2.xz
```

It is mentioned here
https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/18301. Thanks to Sasha Aliashkevich for providing this option.